# Listview incorrect displays columns

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp

I have three columns. I setup header of `ListView` to display data - its work correct. I similarly setup `ListView ItemTemplate` but it incorrect displays data.

```
  <Grid>
            <ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Column="0">
                   <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid  Background="Gray">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <TextBlock Text="Блюдо" Grid.Column="0"         VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,2,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"  FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="Цена" Grid.Column="1"          VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,2,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"  FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="Количество"  Grid.Column="2"   VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,2,0,0" FontWeight="Bold"  FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.HeaderTemplate>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid >
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding bludo}" Grid.Column="0"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,2,0,0"  FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding tsena}" Grid.Column="1"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,2,0,0"  FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding kol}"   Grid.Column="2"  VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="7,2,0,0"  FontSize="18" ></TextBlock>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
            </Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried to set horizontal content alignment in item's container style, so that items will be stretched to full width? [Sample here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38028233/2681948)

Comment: i remove horizontal alignment. Similary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that in `ListViewItem`, it's `HorizontalContentAlignment` property is set to `Left` by default. This property indicates the horizontal alignment of the control's content. When it is set to `Left`, the `ListViewItem`'s content i.e the `Grid` in your `DataTemplate` will be left aligned. So the `Gird` won't take the whole width of the ListView and you will see the "strange" layout like your screenshot.

To see this clearly, we can check [ListViewItem styles and templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt299136.aspx), in its default style, we can see

```
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
```

To fix this issue, we can set the `HorizontalContentAlignment` property to `Stretch` like:

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" Grid.Column="0">
    <ListView.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="Gray">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="7,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Блюдо" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="7,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Цена" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="7,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Количество" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.HeaderTemplate>

    <!--  Add this in your code  -->
    <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
        </Style>
    </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Margin="7,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding bludo}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="7,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding tsena}" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Margin="7,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="18" Text="{Binding kol}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```