# UWP How to keep ListViewItems centered while zooming

Tags: uwp-xaml

I have a list of images that I want to display.  The user should be able to zoom in and out.  I'm able to manage that much just fine, but I would like the list centered on the page as well.  Whenever I zoom out the list moves to the left.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38027960/listviewitem-horizontal-strechting-uwp-10) post that looked helpful, but setting the ItemContainerStyle didn't help me.  I've played around a bit with the HorizontalAlignments of several controls (trying multiple combinations of stretch and center.  The overall effect is essentially the same (list moves to the left when I zoom out).

Here's my XAML:

```
<Grid >
    <ListView SelectionMode="None" 
              ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Enabled" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
              BorderBrush="Red"
              BorderThickness="1"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
        <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Image Source="/Assets/StoreLogo.png"
                   Width="500"/>
            </Grid>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image Source="/Assets/StoreLogo.png"
                   Width="500"/>
            </Grid>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Image Source="/Assets/StoreLogo.png"
                   Width="500"/>
            </Grid>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            BorderBrush="Blue"
                            BorderThickness="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>


</Grid>
```

Comment: Hi, I tested your code, the picture list is centered on the page, and it is always centered when I adjust the width of the window, and it looks fine. Do you want to reduce / enlarge the picture while the window width is being adjusted?

Comment: I haven't been adjusting the window size. I've been using my touch screen to zoom in and out. I haven't tested as much using the keyboard to zoom, but I'm pretty sure it does the same thing.

Comment: Hi, From the perspective of keyboard and mouse operations, the zoom center of the `ScrollViewer` is where the `Pointer` is. On the touch screen, the zoom center of the `ScrollViewer` is the position between the fingers. Currently, `ScrollViewer` does not provide related APIs to force the setting of the zoom center point.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT, when you zoom in and out does that seem to be what's happening for you?  I just tested again, this time making sure to put the mouse pointer at the center of the image (which when the page first loaded was also the center of the window), and zoomed in and out (using ctrl and + or -) and the position of the pointer does not seem to be the zoom center point (not even close) unless I am misunderstanding what you're saying.  On touch, fingers don't seem to be zoom center point either.

Comment: I just edited the code to ensure horizontalscrolling is enabled.  The edit does not affect the zooming issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect there to be a more elegant solution, but this seems to have the right behavior:

```
<Grid >
    <ListView SelectionMode="None" 
              ScrollViewer.ZoomMode="Enabled" 
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
              BorderBrush="Red"
              BorderThickness="1"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled"
              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              Loaded="ListView_Loaded"
              Name="lstImage" >
        <ListViewItem >
            <Image Source="/Assets/StoreLogo.png"
                   Width="500"/>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem >
            <Image Source="/Assets/StoreLogo.png"
                   Width="500"/>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListViewItem >
            <Image Source="/Assets/StoreLogo.png"
                   Width="500"/>
        </ListViewItem>
        <ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            BorderBrush="Blue"
                            BorderThickness="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ListView>


</Grid>
```

The code behind:

```
private void ListView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is ListView lv)) return;

    var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(lv, 0) as Border;
    var sv = border?.Child as ScrollViewer;
    sv.ViewChanged += ScrollViewer_ViewChanged;
}

private void ScrollViewer_ViewChanged(object sender, ScrollViewerViewChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (!(sender is ScrollViewer sv)) return;
    if (!(lstImage?.ItemsPanelRoot is StackPanel sp)) return;

    sp.Width = sv.ZoomFactor > 1 ? double.NaN : lstImage.ActualWidth;
}
```